# n-up printing of beamer slides with empty right-hand side

Tags: beamer, printing

I'm creating a presentation with LaTeX beamer and want to print out some handouts. The handout should fit onto a A4 page and should have the following format. The page is (virtually) split in 4 parts. On the upper and lower left hand side are slides *n* and *n+1*, on the upper and lower right hand side should be some lines. So each participant can write some (side)notes on it. How can I realize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the two slides per page an absolute requirement? If you can live with four slides per page (plus space for notes in the right hand side), you may look to the answer I gave some time ago to a similar query:

[Printing beamer slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/printing-beamer-slides/4773#4773)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @qbi: Just a side note: If you also use the `textpos` package for absolute positioning of material on beamer slides (as recommended by the beamer manual), this does not go well together with n-up solutions that built on `pgfpages`. Both interact badly on the shipout-level: the `textpos` content is **not** shifted or scaled (which was the reason I stopped using `pgfpages`).

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish such tasks easily with the `pdfnup` command, which is part of the `pdfjam` tool suite. For instance

```
pdfnup --a4paper --landscape --nup 1x2 --scale 0.85 --offset '-6cm 0cm' --pagecolor 200,200,200 presentation.pdf
```

yields the following layout (I have set the background color to light gray with `--pagecolor 200,200,200`, so that the actual layout becomes visible.)

[image: Output of pdfnup call]

Technically, `pdfjam` is based on the `pdfpages` LaTeX package (and understands all its options). It internally creates a latex-file and calls `pdflatex` on it to achieve its goals. Hence, if you do not want install another tool, you could also apply a "LaTeX only" solution. The LaTeX file generated by `pdfnup` for the above command line is:

```
\batchmode
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{color} \definecolor{bgclr}{RGB}{200,200,200} \pagecolor{bgclr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[nup=2x1,nup=1x2,scale=0.85,offset=-6cm 0cm]{presentation.pdf,-}
\end{document}
```

I recommend, however, to install `pdfjam` (if you do not already have it). In any case you could check out the [pdfpages documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdfg2=TfAEbFiZBxGm1DYj11jWtA) for a detailed description of options and possibilities.