# Frame numbering with multiple frames in a page in beamer

Tags: beamer, printing, presentations, pgfpages

I am working on a `beamer` presentation where I number frames using

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \hspace{1em}%
 \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
```

Now I want a printable version with 4 frames per page, so I used *Loop Space*'s reply at this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/printing-beamer-slides/4775#4775). But incorporating this creates a problem when frame number exceeds 4. For my current 8 frame slide, frames are numbered: 1/4, 2/4, ..., 8/4. How can I fix that (i.e., frames are numbered this way: 1/8, 2/8, ..., 8/8)?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, english, aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}

\mode<handout>
{
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{4 on 1 boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=4,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}


  \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 boxed}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]
  \nofiles
}


\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \hspace{1em}%
 \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Frame 1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 3
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 4
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Frame 5
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 6
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 7
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 8
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a bit in the "black magic" camp so I'm posting as a comment. If you comment out `\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 boxed}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]` and
  `\nofiles` and compile until you get the numbers right (like 1/8,2/8,...,8/8), then you can uncomment the two lines above and the numbers will stay right.

Comment: Wow! That worked. Do you have enough time to explain it mo me, please?

Comment: I added an answer, too long for a comment...

Comment: By the way, why do you have the `\nofiles` macro loaded in the first place? If you comment it `\inserttotalframenumber` will give you the right number. So if you don't need it for some specific purpose, just remove it and you're set.

Comment: @dcmst Yeah, I did that already (but thought it is not worth mentioning here). `:-)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What the "black magic" method does is to take advantage of the `\nofiles` macro, that prevents modification of the `.aux` file.

If we comment out

```
%\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 boxed}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]
%\nofiles
```

We get a 1 frame on 1 page document with correct page numbering. Looking into the .aux file now (last line), we get:

```
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\def \inserttotalframenumber {8}}} % 8 is the number we want for the total frame count
```

Which is the correct value, since now the pages are counted one on one.

At this point we uncomment the two lines above:

```
 \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 boxed}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]
 \nofiles
```

`\nofiles` will ensure that the `.aux` file is not modified, so that it will keep the correct total number.

Of course the black magic fails as soon as we add another frame/page, so the enchantment must be used when the document is complete, otherwise bad things will happens (so they say...).

[image]

Comment: *So they say* do not use black magic? `:-)`. Thanks. It is helpful.